# Is there a better way to optimize the sql query using Linq?

Tags: sql-server, linq

I am trying to get count details from two tables.The count depends on **table1.data** field
Below is the query

```
SELECT 'ALL'    AS Type, 
Count(*) AS Cnt 
FROM   table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE  table1.id = 2683 

UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NO TYPE' As Type, 
Count(*) AS Cnt 
FROM   table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE  table1.id = 2683 
AND Isnull(table1.data, '') = '' 

UNION ALL 
SELECT Isnull(table1.data, '') As Type, 
Count(*)                    AS Cnt 
FROM   table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE  table1.id = 2683 
AND Isnull(table1.data, '') <> '' 
GROUP  BY Isnull(table1.data, '')
```

And the output should be

```
Type             Cnt
--------------  -----
ALL               4
NO TYPE           0
Type1             3
```

I was trying to use **Case statements** but I failed.Any suggestions please.
**Updated**
the Actual sql query is

```
SELECT 'ALL'    AS FloorNoteType, 
       Count(*) AS Cnt 
FROM   floor_notes 
       INNER JOIN floor_note_xref 
               ON floor_notes.floor_note_id = floor_note_xref.floor_note_id 
WHERE  floor_note_xref.inmate_id = 2683 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'NO TYPE', 
       Count(*) AS Cnt 
FROM   floor_notes 
       INNER JOIN floor_note_xref 
               ON floor_notes.floor_note_id = floor_note_xref.floor_note_id 
WHERE  floor_note_xref.inmate_id = 2683 
       AND Isnull(floor_note_type, '') = '' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Isnull(floor_note_type, '') AS FloorNoteType, 
       Count(*)                    AS Cnt 
FROM   floor_notes 
       INNER JOIN floor_note_xref 
               ON floor_notes.floor_note_id = floor_note_xref.floor_note_id 
WHERE  floor_note_xref.inmate_id = 2683 
       AND Isnull(floor_note_type, '') <> '' 
GROUP  BY Isnull(floor_note_type, '')
```

Comment: If you can't write a good SQL query, what makes you think that adding an abstraction like LINQ is going to make it faster?

Comment: Looks like you only need a `GROUP BY table1.data` and a single `ISNULL(data,'NO TYPE')` in the `SELECT` clause, ie `SELECT ISNULL(table1.data,'NO TYPE') as Type,Count(*) FROM table1 inner join .. where ... GROUP BY table1.data`. You could get the grand total with the `WITH ROLLUP` clause in `GROUP BY`, but that will conflict with the null `data` results.

Comment: Optimising a query with linq is like trying to paint an old master with a stencil or win Le Mans in a Volkswagen Beetle.

Comment: @Jodrell  Respect for Volkswagen Beetle... it was my first car and I still think it could surprise you at Le Mans too ... (I'm joking :-) )

Comment: @etsa these guys took it seriously though http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/picturegalleries/howaboutthat/11164032/Jet-powered-VW-Beetle-that-goes-like-a-rocket.html

Comment: Do you want NULLs and empty strings to be treated the same and be counted as `NO TYPE`? Does `table1.data` contain empty strings or whitespaces?

Comment: I'd say that optimising an SQL query by using LINQ, is like trying to write a Japanese haiku poem by using English and Google Translate. Which is to say, it's hard to optimize one abstraction (SQL) by using an abstraction of that abstraction (LINQ).

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve all totals using a single query with the [WITH ROLLUP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx) clause:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN 
            GROUPING(table1.data) = 1 THEN 'ALL'
       ELSE 
            ISNULL(table1.data, 'NO TYPE')
  END AS Type,
  count(*) Cnt
FROM 
    table1 
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE  table1.id = 2683 
GROUP  BY table1.data WITH ROLLUP
```

`WITH ROLLUP` generates hierarchical sub-totals for each field in the `GROUP BY` clause all the way to a grand total.

Fields that don't take part in a sub-total have a NULL value, which means that null keys and subtotals can get mixed up. The `GROUPING(..)` function checks to see whether a result row is the grand total for a specific field.

In this case there is only a single grouping field, so `GROUPING(table1.data)` will return 1 only for the row that corresponds to the grand total

Comment: `data = ''` and `data = NULL` must be in a same group

Comment: @Triv that's not obvious from the question or query. Even so, it's easy to modify the query *without* using `ISNULL` in the `GROUP BY` clause.